# Using SQL Server MDF file directly

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to connect to an .mdf file (SQL Server) directly like we connect to msaccess db files, without a server installed? I want to do it for my web site because the webhost might not like me having more then 1 database.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server is a **server** (as the name already implies) - so **no**, you cannot use a .mdf file with having a **server** component available somewhere. You can always install and use the **free** SQL Server Express - even for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a possibility as far as I know.. Maybe you should try with SQL Server Compact edition.

Comment: Yes, Compact would work - but it cannot handle .mdf files (it uses .sdf files which are incompatible)

Comment: You're right. I didn't mean to use SQL Compact for accessing mdf files, but rather to use it instead of standard SQL Server.